# How to show expandable cells when we click on particular cell on slider menu in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, I have added one menu slider like the first screen below, and when I click at row one in that slider menu, I want to show an expandable list like the second image. I tried so much but I can't make it.

My menu slider code:

```
.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIToolbar *toolBar;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *view1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *backgroundView;

-(void)menubtn:(UIView *)myView;

@end

----------------------------

.m file

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *items;
    UITableView *tableView1;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize toolBar,view1,label1,backgroundView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@" Raju",@" Krishna",@" Mahesh",@" Goutham",@" Pawan",@" Honey",@" Bobby",@" Chanti",@"Pandu", nil];

    tableView1.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-140, 0, 140, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    tableView1.delegate = self;
    tableView1.dataSource = self;

    [tableView1 registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [self.view addSubview:tableView1];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return items.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 85.0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewCell *headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 55, 100, 21)];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    headerLabel.text = @"Apple";
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [headerCell addSubview:headerLabel];

    UIView *underLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 85, 140, 2)];
    underLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerCell addSubview:underLine];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 70, 55)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"];
    [headerCell addSubview:imgView];

    headerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return headerCell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {

        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(IBAction)menubtn:(id)sender
{
    if (tableView1.frame.origin.x == 0)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width, backgroundView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(-140, 0, 140, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width, backgroundView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == Nil)
    {
        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    Cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];

    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    Cell.selectedBackgroundView = view1;

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 380, 2)];/// change size as you need.

    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    // you can also put image here
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return Cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    label1.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundView.frame.size.width, backgroundView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(-140, 0, 140, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

@end
```

First screen:

[image]

Second screen:

[image]

When I click the first on slider menu, I want to expand the cells like below second screen. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the following code to drop Expandable Cells into a UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];    
    return cell;
}
```

Code for expanding & collapsing rows goes in your TableView's `DidSelectRow` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break; 
        }
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {        
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a method to help minimize-maximize/expand-collapse rows:

```
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];        
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }
        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

[Download code from here](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/)

Comment: iwant expandable list in slider menu using objective c

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own structure for your item array:

```
struct MyItem
{
    NSString *yourData;
    Bool *isChild;
} myItem;
```

so you can manipulate an array of MyItem instead of an array of NSString. Then when you click on the cell (didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:, you declared it twice by the way), add your element "Raju 1" and "Raju 2" to the table by setting isChild to true, and reload the table.

Then on the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: function you will be able to stylise the cell if isChild is true or not.

Hope it helps!

Comment: please modified my code and explain clearly and i am not under stand what your saying